# How to add more than one value to a variable in ansible playbook?

Tags: variables, ansible

I have defined a value to variable in my playbook as :

```
 war_name: abc
```

and i m calling this war_name in the roles as :

```
- name: Download war file
   get_url:
    url=http://url/directory/packages/tomcat/{{ war_name }}.war
```

Now the problem is I have to assign 2 values to variable war_name in playbook
like

```
war_name: abc,xyz
```

How can i do this in my playbook?

If used with_items as :

```
- name: Download war file
       get_url:
        url=http://url/directory/packages/tomcat/{{ item }}.war
   with_items:
     - abc
     - xyz
   when: "'server' in app_name"
```

It results in an error as :

> TASK [tomcat : Download war file]
>   ********************************************** failed: [10.x.x.x] (item=abc) => {"failed": true, "item": "abc", "msg": "missing required
>   arguments: dest"} failed: [10.x.x.x] (item=xyz) => {"failed": true,
>   "item": "xyz", "msg": "missing required arguments: dest"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `dest` argument that is required for `get_url`

Here is the modified version of your task:

```
- name: Download war file
  get_url:
    url: "http://url/directory/packages/tomcat/{{ item }}.war"
    dest: "/path-where-you-want-to-place/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - abc
    - xyz
  when: "'server' in app_name"
```

Hope that help you

Comment: exactly , get_url needs the `dest`to put the file

Comment: That was a stupid mistake from my end..Thanks Guys that works .. :)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is something like this

```
war_name:
  war1: one
  war2: two
```

This is basically a dictionary. Though i am not sure what actually you wanna do here? I guess you want to place 2 wars at a same location with different names, if that is the case you can actually use `with_items`

Comment: Yes i want to use 2 wars in same location , i cannot use two different names because my another playbook is also using same role and that has just one value assigned to variable war_name.. I used with_items as : url=http://url/packages/tomcat/{{ item }}.war
   with_items:
     - abc
     - xyz
but this doesnot work, do u have a code i can use with "with_items"

Comment: what error does it throws ? can u update the question also with the error or "unchanged" stuff